# Get value of TextView from Button onClick and pass value to TextView via TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, android-button, textwatcher

What I want my app to do is to calculate an average and display it in a TextView.

I have a layout with two buttons (button0 and button1) and six TextViews. When I press one of the buttons, my app gets the count of the number of clicks it is pressed, and the same thing with the other button. And it also gets the count of the total number of clicks the two buttons are pressed. So if I divide the number of clicks button0 is pressed by the number of total clicks the two buttons are pressed and I multiply it by 100, I get the percentage clicks that button is pressed.

So this is the code:

```
    Button button0, button1;
    int click_button0, click_button1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

    final TextView times_0_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.times_0);
    final TextView percentage_0_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.percentage_0);
    final TextView times_1_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.times_1);
    final TextView percentage_1_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.percentage_1);
    final TextView total_clicks_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_clicks);

    button0 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click_button0 = click_button0 + 1;
            total_clicks = click_button0 + click_button1;
            total_clicks_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total_clicks));

            if (click_button0 == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number 0 has apperared 1 time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number 0 has apperared " + click_button0 + " times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            times_0_tv.setText(String.valueOf(click_button0));
            times_1_tv.setText(String.valueOf(click_button1));

        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click_button1 = click_button1 + 1;
            total_clicks = click_button0 + click_button1;
            total_clicks_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total_clicks));

            if (click_button1 == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number 1 has apperared 1 time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number 1 has apperared " + click_button1 + " times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            times_0_tv.setText(String.valueOf(click_button0));
            times_1_tv.setText(String.valueOf(click_button1));

        }
    });

    times_0_tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String times0String = times_0_tv.getText().toString();
            String times1String = times_1_tv.getText().toString();
            String totaltimesString = total_clicks_tv.getText().toString();

            // convert the String into a double
            if (times0String.length() > 0) {
                click_button0 = (int) Double.parseDouble(times0String);
            }
            if (times1String.length() > 0) {
                click_button1 = (int) Double.parseDouble(times1String);
            }
            if (totaltimesString.length() > 0) {
                total_clicks = (int) Double.parseDouble(totaltimesString);
            }

            // calculate re
            double percent0calc = calc_percent0();

            // set the label for re1Text
            percentage_0_tv.setText(Double.toString(percent0calc));
        }
    });

    times_1_tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String times0String = times_0_tv.getText().toString();
            String times1String = times_1_tv.getText().toString();
            String totaltimesString = total_clicks_tv.getText().toString();

            // convert the String into a double
            if (times0String.length() > 0) {
                click_button0 = (int) Double.parseDouble(times0String);
            }
            if (times1String.length() > 0) {
                click_button1 = (int) Double.parseDouble(times1String);
            }
            if (totaltimesString.length() > 0) {
                total_clicks = (int) Double.parseDouble(totaltimesString);
            }

            // calculate re
            double percent1calc = calc_percent1();

            // set the label for re1Text
            percentage_1_tv.setText(Double.toString(percent1calc));
        }
    });
}

double calc_percent0() {
    return click_button0/total_clicks;
}
double calc_percent1() {
    return click_button1/total_clicks;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the layout:

[image]

**The problem comes when I press a button, the percentage is 0%, it doesn't change. The idea is, for example, if I press button0 3 times and button1 1 time, percentage for 0 is 75% and percentage for 1 is 25%. Any idea will be welcomed, thanks!**

**EDIT:** I have deleted implemention of TextWatcher and I have added some lines to the code. It is working fine when I click button0 because it shows the percentage of clicks is 100%, but the moment I click button1, both percentages turn 0, and I don't get any percentage. It seems there is a problem when passing the value of the total clicks to the percentage calc.

Here is the code now for the Fragment:

```
Button button0, button1;
int click_button0, click_button1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

final TextView times_0_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.times_0);
    final TextView percentage_0_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.percentage_0);
    final TextView times_1_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.times_1);
    final TextView percentage_1_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.percentage_1);
    final TextView total_clicks_tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total_clicks);

    button0 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click_button0 = click_button0 + 1;
            total_clicks = click_button0 + click_button1;
            total_clicks_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total_clicks));

            if (click_button0 == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number 0 has apperared 1 time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number 0 has apperared " + click_button0 + " times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            times_0_tv.setText(String.valueOf(click_button0));
            times_1_tv.setText(String.valueOf(click_button1));
            percent0 = click_button0/total_clicks;
            percentage_0_tv.setText(String.valueOf(percent0));
        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click_button1 = click_button1 + 1;
            total_clicks = click_button0 + click_button1;
            total_clicks_tv.setText(String.valueOf(total_clicks));

            if (click_button1 == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number 1 has apperared 1 time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Number 1 has apperared " + click_button1 + " times", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            times_0_tv.setText(String.valueOf(click_button0));
            times_1_tv.setText(String.valueOf(click_button1));
            percent1 = click_button1/total_clicks;
            percentage_1_tv.setText(String.valueOf(percent1));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just calculate and set the percentage in the buttons onClick? You want to update the percentage when the button is clicked, therefore the logic should be within the buttons OnClickListener, not the TextWatcher.

Also, instead of getting the values from your TextViews, use the variables you already have: `int click_button0, click_button1;`

Do the calculation in the onClick using the variables values and then set the TextViews value and it should work as intended.

Also, if you are going to try and parse a string as a number double, int etc you should surround it in a try catch in case of an exception. And in this case you should just use Integer.parseInt instead of using parseDouble and then casting it to an int.

**Edit:** Ah yep, that'd be because you are dividing an int by an int, so the result will also be an int. A quick fix is to cast one of the numbers to a float/double, and when you divide you will get a decimal number. 
`((double) click_button0) / total_clicks;`

You should also update both percentages at the same time, seeing as one number changing affects the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was really useful. I have edited my question with your suggestions, but the problem still exists. Hope you have any idea, thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer to help with your edit, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, finally I got it with your help!